# Error al compilar java en la cmd

Tags: java

He instalado java un ordenador por primera vez y al intentar compilar en java con el comando javac me dice "el sistema no puede encontrar el texto del mensaje para el mensaje numero 0x2331 en el archivo de mensajes para aplication". Cabe destacar que ya reinstale varias veces el jdk asi mismo la variable en path con la ruta de la carpeta bin y agregue la variable JAVA_HOME

La ruta en la que instale el jdk es: C:\ Program Files\ Java\ jdk.8.0_231 ahi se encuentra, el path es en la variable path y es: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin y agregue como variable nueva JAVA_HOME y el valor de esta es: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_231 Estoy intentando compilar codigo para principiantes HolaMundo, OperacionesAritmeticas etc.
Al escribir java -version en cmd si muestra la version Al escribir java --version en cmd da los siguientes errores Unrecognized option: --version Error: could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has ocurred. Program will exist.

Comment: Pues supongo que has instalado la JRE para correr los programas y la JDK para crear programas de java. En todo caso te faltaria la JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu computadora tiene windows 10 lo que tienes que hacer es instalar el JDK, yo tengo la version 1.8.0_221 tienes que agregar en el path lo siguiente. Por ejemplo, en mi equipo, la ruta es `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin`. Probablemente, en tu caso sea muy parecido, aunque puede cambiar el número de versión de JDK y la arquitectura si es x86 o x64.

Una vez que tengas la ruta, debes hacer clic sobre el cuadro de texto Valor de la variable e irte al final del texto que contiene (por ejemplo, pulsando la tecla Fin). Una vez allí, pulsamos la tecla ; (punto y coma) y, a continuación, escribimos la ruta anterior. En definitiva, nos debe quedar algo así: `;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin`solo te resta validar los cambios y probar